# How to label each points in seaborn catplot with y values

Tags: label, seaborn, catplot

I'm trying to get y coordinate values of the each points plotted in seaborn catplot. I have found the sources how to get it if I'm plotting catplot with bar-plots but not with points.

[image: Image for reference]

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Hey, welcome to the community! Could you provide the code you used and (a sample of) the data to be plotted? [See this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: As per the duplicate [example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DihNN.png)